# java assistance for looping the main code

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Im trying to write a code and i used the do while loop in an atempt to loop my main code after the user types in y or yes (case insensitive) into an InputDialog.

here is the code, the only error is that a } needs to be put in after the do { but eve if i put it into the place I want, it doesn't work, also, it does not recognize thw while statement at the bottom, please help.

```
package tictactoemain;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
* JFrame to hold TicTacToe board.
*/
public class TicTacToeFrame extends JFrame
{     

    **do {** //do starts here
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // Indicate whose turn it is
   private char whoseTurn = 'X';
   private boolean gameOver = false;

   // Create cell grid using an Array
   private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[3][3];

   // Create a status label
   JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel("X's turn to play");

   /**
    * No-argument Constructor
    * @return 
    */
   public TicTacToeFrame()
   {
       // Panel to hold cells
       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               panel.add(cells[i][j] = new Cell());

       panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
       jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));

       add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
   // Determine if it's a tie
   /**
    * Determine if game board is full.
    * @return True, if game board is full. Otherwise, false.
    */
    public boolean isFull()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               if (cells[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
                   return false;
       return true;
    }
    // Check to see if a player (Token) has won
   /**
    * Determines if a given token has won.
    * @param token Token to test for winning
    * @return True, if the token has won. Otherwise, false.
    */
   public boolean isWon(char token)
   {
       // check rows
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           if ((cells[i][0].getToken() == token)
                   && (cells[i][1].getToken() == token)
                   && (cells[i][2].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       // check columns
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           if ((cells[0][j].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][j].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][j].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }
       // check diagonals
       if ((cells[0][0].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][2].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       if ((cells[0][2].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][0].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       return false;
   }

    /**
    * Defines a cell in a TicTacToe game board.
    */
    public class Cell extends JPanel
    {
       /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // token of this cell
       private char token = ' ';

       /**
        * Constructor
        */
       public Cell()
       {
           setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
           addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
       }

       /**
        * Gets the token of the cell.
        * @return The token value of the cell.
        */
       public char getToken()
       {
           return token;
       }

       /**
        * Sets the token of the cell.
        * @param c Character to use as token value.
        */
       public void setToken(char c)
       {
           token = c;
           repaint();
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
           super.paintComponent(g);

           if (token == 'X')
           {
               g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
               g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);
           }

           else if (token == 'O')
           {
               g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
           }
       }
       // MouseListener to listen for a click to place a token
       private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
       {

        private String playAgain;
        private Object playYes;
        private Object playNo;

        @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
           {
               if (gameOver)
                   return;

               // if condition not met, the game is not over
               if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ')
                   setToken(whoseTurn);

               // Check game status
               if (isWon(whoseTurn))
               {
                   jlblStatus.setText("Congratulations " + whoseTurn +  ", You Are Winnner! Game Over! Exit And Restart The Program To Play Again!" );
                   whoseTurn = ' ';
                   gameOver = true;
               }
               else if (isFull())
               {
                   jlblStatus.setText("Tie game! Game over!");
                   whoseTurn = ' ';
                   gameOver = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
                   jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn to play.");

               }
             // and ends here, while statement is below
               {
               // if the game is over, this will run           
               if (gameOver == true)

                   playAgain = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play again?");

               // if statement that either restarts the game or closes it depending on the yes/y (cases are ignored) answer

               while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y") | playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
               {
                   playYes = ("Yes? Okay, have fun!");

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, playYes );
      }   
     }         
    }// End of Win condition checker
   } // End class MyMouseListener           
  }
} // End class TicTacToeFrame
```

Comment: suppose you use a do while loop to solve your issue. these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029538/loop-to-repeat-a-game-of-tic-tac-toe) & [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388383/tic-tac-toe-program-loop-problems) have addresses the same issue i think.

Comment: I notice that you are using singulars `|` - be sure you understand this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564484/2310289

Comment: Why don't you just use `main(null)` if the user wants to play again? this runs the main method.

Comment: how could I implement that, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize all of your variables from a single method. This way you could initialize the game at the beginning of the program with it and if the player requests to play the game again you could call the same method thus bringing the program back to its original state.

```java
private void init() {
    whoseTurn = 'X';
    gameOver = false;
    jlblStatus = new JLabel("X's turn to play");
    for(Cell[] ca : cells) {
        for(Cell c : ca) {
            c.setToken(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

My example might not include all variables but you could tweak it to suit your needs.

The do-while loop is not recognized because it is outside of a method.

Comment: will this  allow me to ask the user if they want to play again and based on their answer restart the program?

Comment: Yes. If they say yes then call the `init()` method and it should reset the game if configured properly, if they say no then simply exit the game as you normally would.